# Could not load assembly "System.Xaml.Hosting"

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I install two library for my Android App from Visual Studio.
*Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
Install-Package modernhttpclient*

And this error has occurred, there may be compatibility issues here, and I still have not figured out how to solve.

*System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Xaml.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.Xaml.Hosting.dll'...*

Any suggestion on why am I getting this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the DLL "System.Xaml.Hosting.dll" From the Folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.Hosting
in your Folder bin/Debug